# Vuex store not updated when called from promise resolution

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

I have an array that is bound to a vuex data store and exposed as a computed property through the `mapGetters` helper. This array is called `items`, and I call a REST API to update it in the `created()` hook of the component. The vuex action I have for this returns a promise in which the API is accessed and the mutator called (which updates the `items` array) before resolving. My understanding of promises tells me that my `then` calls should safely occur after the asynchronous action completes, yet if I try to access `items` from the promise resolution, it is empty despite the array certainly being populated by the API call. Why isn't this working how I expect?

The code is all over but here are the relevant parts

Component:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      items: 'allHistoryItems'
    }),
// ...
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchList').then(console.log(this.items))
  }
```

Action:

```
  fetchList: ({ commit }) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetchList().then(response => {
        commit(types.FETCH_LIST, response.data)
        resolve(response)
      })
    })
  }
```

I can access the API response from the component, but as mentioned, `items` is empty. Does the reactivity not kick in until after the promise resolves?

Comment: [Avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - having said that, how does the "Action" change items? I can't see the connection

Comment: ahhh `.then(console.log(this.items))` ... should be `.then(() => console.log(this.items))` ... .then needs a function as an argument, not the result of calling console.log (which is undefined by the way)

Comment: I'll check the article. Items is mapped to a getter that manipulates and returns the list fetched by the API.

Comment: ignore my first comment, the error you made is in my second comment

Comment: Go figure it's something as basic as that. I'll test it later but make it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short

```
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchList').then(console.log(this.items))
}
```

When `created` is called, it executes:

```
this.$store.dispatch('fetchList')
```

followed **immediately** by

```
console.log(this.items)
```

No waiting for anything, then, when `this.$store.dispatch('fetchList')` resolves, `.then` is called like `.then(undefined)` ... because `console.log(this.items)` returns `undefined`

change this to

```
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchList').then(() => console.log(this.items));
}
```

As a bonus - removing the promise constructor anti-pattern:

```
fetchList: ({ commit }) => fetchList() 
    .then(response => {
        commit(types.FETCH_LIST, response.data);
        return response;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your new Promise construction is simply redundant. Inspec this simple example if it is doing wha you want:

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    hero: []
  },
  mutations: {
    updateHero (state, payload) {

      state.hero = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async loadHero ({commit}, payload) {
      var response = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
      commit('updateHero', await response.json())
    }
  }
})

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    hero () {
      return this.$store.state.hero
    }
  },
  methods: Vuex.mapActions(['loadHero'])
})
```

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Hero name is: <span v-cloak>{{ hero.name }}</span><br>
  <button @click="loadHero">Load hero personal data</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
```